# Docker compose run only dependencies

Tags: java, docker, docker-compose, microservices

I have microservice defined in docker-compose.yml and dependencies in docker-compose-dependencies.yml

Is it possible to run only dependencies? I don't want to restart them each time, prefer to keep them for few hours and run many debug sessions with my microservice from IntelliJ

EDIT:

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  micro-name:
    image: package/image:1.0.0
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
```

docker-compose-dependencies.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:
  mongodb:
    image: mongo
    ports:
      - '27017:27017'
```

It runs microservice but i want mongo only:

```
docker-compose up
```

How to resolve is to specify file name (before i couldnt find this, dont know why):

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose-dependencies.yml up
```

Comment: Can you edit your question to include some minimal working examples of the `docker-compose.yml` and `docker-compose-dependencies.yml` files you are working with? We would need to see how those files are set up before it's possible to answer your question without having to guess about what you're doing.